# PHP mail sending problems

Tags: php, email, smtp

i was created Normal php script with headers for send the mail to my clients, my clients are have business mail account on their own domain mail account. The mail function working fine for any personal account like gmail,yahoo. But if i send the mail to any business mail account it's not going to in-box , but the mail status say successfully send. i had checked my mail function headers  it's also looking fine. and also i had tried another php mail function like PHP-Mailer, RMail , These third-party function also return value true, but mail was not in inbox. my server os in Linux, please clear this any one, thanks advance

Comment: I had this problem once, my e-mails didn't pass the spamfilter for some reason.

Comment: " it's not going to in-box" so is it going in the `SPAM` or nowhere ??

Comment: not in spam also swanpnesh

Answer (score 0):

Your mailfunction will return successfully sent whenever the mail has successfully left the server. whether the server of the recipient picks up the email, and accepts it, is unknown to your mailfunction, and totally out of your hands.
Since you mention that your testmails being sent to your personal emailaddresses all arrive, I assume that the problem is not in your PHP program, but in the recipients mailserver not accepting the email. Most probably they are being filtered as spam. A good way to prevent this is by using a real emailaddress on a valid domain and an SMTP server on that domain (same IP-Address) to send the mail from. Otherwise, many mailservers will see that the IP-address from the program sending the mail, and the IP-address of the mailserver in the "FROM" field are not the same, and label it as spam.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, can you show some example for this